# How to create a listView from string array

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi I am trying to get data from a SQLite database and add it into a listview so far I have the following however it is not working. I am not sure if the data is being added into the array correctly. I have a function called ViewAll which is called within onCreate.

I have this within a class called datahelper

```
    public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " +TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;


}
```

and then the following class which is supposed to display the data within a listview

```
   public void ViewAll() {
    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
    String[] data;
    if (res != null) {
        while (res.moveToNext()) {
            data = new String[10];
            data[0] = String.valueOf(res.getInt(0));
            data[1] = res.getString(1);
            data[2] = res.getString(2);
            data[3] = String.valueOf(res.getInt(3));
            data[4] = String.valueOf(res.getFloat(4));
            data[5] = String.valueOf(res.getFloat(5));
            data[6] = String.valueOf(res.getInt(6));
            data[7] = String.valueOf(res.getInt(7));
            data[8] = String.valueOf(res.getInt(8));
            data[9] = String.valueOf(res.getInt(9));

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.display_data_layout, data);

            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.displayview);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should log your arrays size, or just use brake points.

Comment: I am not sure how I would do that could you give me an example please.

Comment: Very good [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this
 ListView mylistview;
    ArrayAdapter listAdapter;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    final String[] items = { "White", "Black", "Red", "Green", "Yellow",
            "Blue", "Pink" };
    // String[] items = new String[]{ "White", "Black", "Red", "Green",
    // "Yellow" ,"Blue","Pink"};

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    mylistview.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // For ListItem Click
    mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            String s = items[position].toString();
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Selected Color is " + s, 3000).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to rework your code. You are reading one entry at a time, creating an adapter, and setting the adapter for that entry. Then you read the next entry, create a new adapter (discarding the earlier one), and setting that adapter. So effectively, only the last row in your table is used.

You are better off starting over, have a look [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter) for how to populate a list view from a cursor.

Comment: Thanks for link I am just looking though now I am also getting the following error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference` is this related to problem I have were it is looping though and overiding the previous array or is it something else?

Comment: This means your findViewById for the listview is returning null. Make sure you are using the correct ID for your listview from the XML.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem, I have reworked my code around the link you mentioned however I am getting another error should I update this question or rewrite a new one?

Comment: If it's closely related to this question, update it, otherwise create a new one.

Comment: Ok I have posted a new  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852993/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-column-id-does-not-exist-error)